# populate form dynamically in angular?

Tags: angular

I am creating dynamic form by getting data from backend. how can i use formcontrol. i getting error stating Cannot find control with name: 'obj.name'.
**how can i initializeForm by iterating over toolData instead hard code intializing.**

```
initializeForm(){
   // here i am intializing manually how can i initialize by iterating over toolData 
    this.formValue=this.fb.group({
      uname:['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']+')]],
      xyz:['',[Validators.required]],
      abc:['',[Validators.required]],
    })
  }
```

```
<form [formGroup]="formValue">
    <span *ngFor="let obj of toolData">
       <label for="obj.name">{{obj.label}}</label>
       <input type="obj.type" id="obj.name" name="obj.name" formControlName="obj.name" value="obj.value" required="obj.required" />
    </span>
</form>
```

```
toolData=[{"type":"text","name":"uname","label":"user Name","value":"default","required":true},
    {"type":"number","name":"xyz","label":"Sample Value","value":"1","min":0,"max":100,"required":true},
    {"type":"number","name":"abc","label":"ABC ","value":"6","min":0,"max":100,"required":true}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(
    ...
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ...
) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initForm(); // init form with default values before u get response from server
    // after getting data from server call initControls()
  }

  // convenience getters for easy access to form fields
  get controls(): {[key: string]: AbstractControl} { return this.form.controls; }
  get someControls(): FormArray { return this.controls.someControls as FormArray; }

initForm(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      someControls: new FormArray([])
    });
}

initControls(): void {
const someControlFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [defaultValue, [Validators.required]],
    });
    this.someControls.push(someControlFormGroup);
}
```

now you can just use formControlName while each controls in template

Answer (score 0):

property binding has been done incorrectly, trying the below code.

```
[formControlName]="obj.name"
```

for more detail, please see the https://angular.io/guide/property-binding